# Language problems associted with a new theme in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarorm

I have installed the latested version of sugarcrm and installed it suite crm theme. Every thing worked fine(in terms of design). Then, I installed russian langauge pack. Language was applied correctly except global controll links. I cleared caches(both browser and sugarcrm). If i enter crm(for example using English language) and logged out and enter using russian language, the global controll links are in English language(while all other elements in russian language). If I clear crm and browser from caches and enter the system(In reverse language order), Global controll links in Russian language while all other elements in english language. I suppose the error associted with caches and sesson. But, I do not know how to solve the issue. Please, help me. Where i need to change in order system work with a new them?

Comment: Have you checked developer mode setting which can be set from admin panel.. ?

Comment: sugar-js is not a correct for this issue, removed

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to the issue. I think that the problem was associted with ajaxheader. Therefore, I disabled them from admin->system settings->settings of ajax